# How to print (echo) messages without line breaks in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, line-breaks

I am creating a `.bash_profile` script, and I have run into a small problem.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
echo -n "Welcome "
whoami
echo -n "!"
```

I would like the output to give something like this:

```
Welcome jsmith!
```

... instead of this:

```
Welcome jsmith
!
```

How can I get all of this onto one line?

Any help is greatly appreciated. If it helps, I'm using the Bash Shell, on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert `$(command)` (new style) or `` `command` `` (old style) to insert the output of a command into a double-quoted string.

```
echo "Welcome $(whoami)!"
```

Note: In a script this will work fine. If you try it at an interactive command line the final `!` may cause you trouble as `!` triggers [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

> #### Command Substitution
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted** *[emphasis added]*.

Comment: Thanks, John. Good catch with the "!", by the way. ;) That is just what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

Use this form. Get rid of `echo` and get away from creating a *subshell*.

```
printf 'Welcome %s!\n' "$USER"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo -ne "Welcome `whoami`!\n"
```

OR

```
echo -ne "Welcome $(whoami)!\n"
```

Comment: First version is ok, but second not. -ne does not suppress the \n created by whoami.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
echo "Welcome $(whoami)!"
```

The `$()` construct executes the command inside it, and evaluates to the output of it.

Another option would be:

```
{
    echo "Welcome "
    whoami
    echo "!"
} | tr -d '\n'
```

Although that's a bit mad.

Whatever you do, you might need single quotes around the `!`. In my shell, `!` is a history metacharacter even inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    echo "Welcome `whoami`!"
```